# Landscape longtable for a very wide table

Tags: longtable

I apologise - I realise this has been asked a million times already, but I've been struggling as I'm not very well-versed in LaTeX.

I have a wide table that goes over several pages that I am trying to fit onto the page. I have re-created the table with dummy text (and many rows shorter).

Copy-pasting from excel into word tells me that it should fit on an A4 page when everything wraps. [image: desired output]

But this is the output I get in overleaf

[image: output]

I've made this using a [table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/), which has worked well for me for other tables.

I'm currently not concerned about the text on the second page floating up - I've had that before and I just force a page break to fix that (or the missing backslash for leftrightarrow - that's just a find/replace job)

I guess I'm trying to figure out how to get the contents of the columns to wrap?

Finally, the code:
I used [this](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-a-masters-slash-doctoral-thesis/mkzrzktcbzfl) template (which in hindsight I now very much regret)

```
\documentclass[
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
english, % ngerman for German
doublespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
%nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
% i think these are all the relevant packages to my question - there are a lot in the preamble since it's a whole thesis using a template 

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[c]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{D0CECE} 
\textbf{Reference} &
  \textbf{Column 1} &
  \textbf{Column 2 that is   descriptive} &
  \textbf{Column 3 that   also contains more information and is long} &
  \textbf{Column 4 is also   long and needs space} &
  \textbf{Column 5} &
  \textbf{Column 6} &
  \textbf{Column 7} &
  \textbf{Column 8 ABC} &
  \textbf{Column9 ABCDE} \\ \hline
\endhead
%
 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
   &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
   &
  results   that are a little long too \\ \cline{7-8} \cline{10-10} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{Smith et al., 2004} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{Rat Rat Mouse} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{Stress Type} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{short description} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{ABC} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{PND100} &
  Female &
  leftrightarrow No Change &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{description that is a bit long to add detail} &
  results   that are a little longer and need to go here too ABCD 1234 \\ \hline
Smith et al., 2004 &
  Rat   Rat Mouse &
  Stress   Type &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
  ABC &
  PND100 &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
  NOT   TESTED &
  NOT   TESTED \\ \hline
Smith et al., 2004 &
  Rat Rat Mouse &
  Stress   Type &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
  ABC &
  PND100 &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
  description   that is a bit long to add detail &
  results   that are a little long too \\ \hline
 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
   &
  Male &
  leftrightarrow No Change &
   &
  results   that are a little long too \\ \cline{7-8} \cline{10-10} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{Smith et al., 2004} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{Rat Rat Mouse} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{Stress Type} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{long description bla bla bla bla} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{ABC} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{PND100} &
  Female &
  ↑   Result &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{description that is a bit long to add detail} &
  leftrightarrow No Change \\ \hline
 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
   &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
   &
   \\ \cline{7-8}
\multirow{-2}{*}{Smith et al., 2004} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{Rat Rat Mouse} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{Stress Type} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{long description bla bla bla bla} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{ABC} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{PND100} &
  Female &
  ↑   Result &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{NOT TESTED} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{NOT TESTED} \\ \hline
 &
   &
   &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
   &
   &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
   &
  results   that are a little longer and need to go here too ABCD 1234 \\ \cline{4-4} \cline{7-8} \cline{10-10} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{Smith et al., 2004} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{Rat Rat Mouse} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{Stress Type} &
  long description bla bla bla bla &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{ABC} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{PND100 but more detail required} &
  Female &
  leftrightarrow No Change &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{description that is a bit long to add detail} &
  results   that are a little longer and need to go here too ABCD 1234 \\ \hline
 &
   &
   &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
   &
   &
  Male &
  leftrightarrow No Change &
   &
  results   that are a little longer and need to go here too ABCD 1234 \\ \cline{4-4} \cline{7-8} \cline{10-10} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{Smith et al., 2004} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{Rat Rat Mouse} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{Stress Type} &
  long description bla bla bla bla &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{ABC} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{PND100 but more detail required} &
  Female &
  ↑   Result &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{description that is a bit long to add detail} &
  results   that are a little longer and need to go here too ABCD 1234 \\ \hline
 &
   &
   &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
   &
   &
  Male &
  leftrightarrow No Change &
   &
  results   that are a little longer and need to go here too ABCD 1234 \\ \cline{4-4} \cline{7-8} \cline{10-10} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{Smith et al., 2004} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{Rat Rat Mouse} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{Stress Type} &
  long description bla bla bla bla &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{ABC} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{PND100 but more detail required} &
  Female &
  ↑   Result &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{description that is a bit long to add detail} &
  results   that are a little longer and need to go here too ABCD 1234 \\ \hline
 &
   &
   &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
   &
   &
  Male &
  leftrightarrow No Change &
   &
  results   that are a little longer and need to go here too ABCD 1234 \\ \cline{4-4} \cline{7-8} \cline{10-10} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{Smith et al., 2004} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{Rat Rat Mouse} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{Stress Type} &
  long description bla bla bla bla &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{ABC} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{PND100 but more detail required} &
  Female &
  ↑   Result &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{description that is a bit long to add detail} &
  results   that are a little longer and need to go here too ABCD 1234 \\ \hline
 &
   &
   &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
   &
   &
  Male &
  leftrightarrow No Change &
   &
  results   that are a little longer and need to go here too ABCD 1234 \\ \cline{4-4} \cline{7-8} \cline{10-10} 
\multirow{-2}{*}{Smith et al., 2004} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{Rat Rat Mouse} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{Stress Type} &
  long description bla bla bla bla &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{ABC} &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{PND100 but more detail required} &
  Female &
  ↑   Result &
  \multirow{-2}{*}{description that is a bit long to add detail} &
  results   that are a little longer and need to go here too ABCD 1234 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

\end{document}

Comment: Can you please complete your given code to be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing....

Comment: @Mensch sorry I'm a newbie - what do you mean? I copied the whole thing in...

Comment: We nned to know which documentclass and which options and which packages you are using. Then we can copy the code and test it on the own computer without guessing ...

Answer (score 1):

- You use private documentclass. Instead it I use `book` and define page layout with `geometry`  package.
- Your table is very large, so you need to do the following:

  - reduce font size
  - allow line breaks in cell with defined column types with prescribed column width
  - replace `\multirow{...}{*}{...}` with `\multirow{-1}{=}{Rat Rat Mouse}` when text in this cell has only one line or width `\multirow{-1}[<number of lines in cell]{=}{Rat Rat Mouse}`
  - redefine horizontal alignment in €multirow cells with `\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}` before table

With correcting all errors in table and defining column width with trial and correcting errors, MWE can be:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} % The class file specifying the document structure
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
% i think these are all the relevant packages to my question - there are a lot in the preamble since it's a whole thesis using a template
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}
\begin{longtable}{|C{5.5em}|C{5.5em}|C{6em}
                  |C{9em}|  C{8em}|  C{5em}|
                  c|        C{5em}|  C{7em}|
                  C{10em}|}
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{D0CECE}
\textbf{Reference} &
  \textbf{Column 1} &
  \textbf{Column 2 that is   descriptive} &
  \textbf{Column 3 that   also contains more information and is long} &
  \textbf{Column 4 is also   long and needs space} &
  \textbf{Column 5} &
  \textbf{Column 6} &
  \textbf{Column 7} &
  \textbf{Column 8 ABC} &
  \textbf{Column 9 ABCDE} \\ \hline
\endhead
%
    &   &   &   &   &   & Male
                            & Result
                                &   &   results that are a
                                        little long too     \\
    \cline{7-8} \cline{10-10}
\multirow{-1}[2]{=}{Smith et al., 2004} &
  \multirow{-1}[2]{=}{Rat Rat Mouse} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{Stress Type} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{short description} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{ABC} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{PND100} &
  Female &
  $\leftrightarrow$ No Change &
  \multirow{-1}[4]{=}{description that is a bit long to add detail} &
  results   that are a little longer and need to go here too ABCD 1234 \\ \hline
  \hline
Smith et al., 2004 &
  Rat   Rat Mouse &
  Stress   Type &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
  ABC &
  PND100 &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
  NOT   TESTED &
  NOT   TESTED \\ \hline
Smith et al., 2004 &
  Rat Rat Mouse &
  Stress   Type &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
  ABC &
  PND100 &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
  description   that is a bit long to add detail &
  results   that are a little long too          \\
  \hline
     &   &   &   &   &   & Male
                            & Result
                                &   &   results that are a
                                        little long too     \\
    \cline{7-8} \cline{10-10}
\multirow{-1}[2]{=}{Smith et al., 2004} &
  \multirow{-1}[2]{=}{Rat Rat Mouse} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{Stress Type} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{short description} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{ABC} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{PND100} &
  Female &
  $\leftrightarrow$ No Change &
  \multirow{-1}[4]{=}{description that is a bit long to add detail} &
  results   that are a little longer and need to go here too ABCD 1234 \\ \hline
  \hline
Smith et al., 2004 &
  Rat   Rat Mouse &
  Stress   Type &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
  ABC &
  PND100 &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
  NOT   TESTED &
  NOT   TESTED \\ \hline
Smith et al., 2004 &
  Rat Rat Mouse &
  Stress   Type &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
  ABC &
  PND100 &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
  description   that is a bit long to add detail &
  results   that are a little long too          \\
  \hline
    &   &   &   &   &   & Male
                            & Result
                                &   &   results that are a
                                        little long too     \\
    \cline{7-8} \cline{10-10}
\multirow{-1}[2]{=}{Smith et al., 2004} &
  \multirow{-1}[2]{=}{Rat Rat Mouse} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{Stress Type} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{short description} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{ABC} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{PND100} &
  Female &
  $\leftrightarrow$ No Change &
  \multirow{-1}[4]{=}{description that is a bit long to add detail} &
  results   that are a little longer and need to go here too ABCD 1234 \\ \hline
  \hline
Smith et al., 2004 &
  Rat   Rat Mouse &
  Stress   Type &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
  ABC &
  PND100 &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
  NOT   TESTED &
  NOT   TESTED \\ \hline
Smith et al., 2004 &
  Rat Rat Mouse &
  Stress   Type &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
  ABC &
  PND100 &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
  description   that is a bit long to add detail &
  results   that are a little long too          \\
  \hline
    &   &   &   &   &   & Male
                            & Result
                                &   &   results that are a
                                        little long too     \\
    \cline{7-8} \cline{10-10}
\multirow{-1}[2]{=}{Smith et al., 2004} &
  \multirow{-1}[2]{=}{Rat Rat Mouse} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{Stress Type} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{short description} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{ABC} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{PND100} &
  Female &
  $\leftrightarrow$ No Change &
  \multirow{-1}[4]{=}{description that is a bit long to add detail} &
  results   that are a little longer and need to go here too ABCD 1234 \\ \hline
  \hline
Smith et al., 2004 &
  Rat   Rat Mouse &
  Stress   Type &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
  ABC &
  PND100 &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
  NOT   TESTED &
  NOT   TESTED \\ \hline
Smith et al., 2004 &
  Rat Rat Mouse &
  Stress   Type &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
  ABC &
  PND100 &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
  description   that is a bit long to add detail &
  results   that are a little long too          \\
  \hline
    &   &   &   &   &   & Male
                            & Result
                                &   &   results that are a
                                        little long too     \\
    \cline{7-8} \cline{10-10}
\multirow{-1}[2]{=}{Smith et al., 2004} &
  \multirow{-1}[2]{=}{Rat Rat Mouse} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{Stress Type} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{short description} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{ABC} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{PND100} &
  Female &
  $\leftrightarrow$ No Change &
  \multirow{-1}[4]{=}{description that is a bit long to add detail} &
  results   that are a little longer and need to go here too ABCD 1234 \\ \hline
  \hline
Smith et al., 2004 &
  Rat   Rat Mouse &
  Stress   Type &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
  ABC &
  PND100 &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
  NOT   TESTED &
  NOT   TESTED \\ \hline
Smith et al., 2004 &
  Rat Rat Mouse &
  Stress   Type &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
  ABC &
  PND100 &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
  description   that is a bit long to add detail &
  results   that are a little long too          \\
  \hline
    &   &   &   &   &   & Male
                            & Result
                                &   &   results that are a
                                        little long too     \\
    \cline{7-8} \cline{10-10}
\multirow{-1}[2]{=}{Smith et al., 2004} &
  \multirow{-1}[2]{=}{Rat Rat Mouse} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{Stress Type} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{short description} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{ABC} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{PND100} &
  Female &
  $\leftrightarrow$ No Change &
  \multirow{-1}[4]{=}{description that is a bit long to add detail} &
  results   that are a little longer and need to go here too ABCD 1234 \\ \hline
  \hline
Smith et al., 2004 &
  Rat   Rat Mouse &
  Stress   Type &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
  ABC &
  PND100 &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
  NOT   TESTED &
  NOT   TESTED \\ \hline
Smith et al., 2004 &
  Rat Rat Mouse &
  Stress   Type &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
  ABC &
  PND100 &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
  description   that is a bit long to add detail &
  results   that are a little long too          \\
  \hline
    &   &   &   &   &   & Male
                            & Result
                                &   &   results that are a
                                        little long too     \\
    \cline{7-8} \cline{10-10}
\multirow{-1}[2]{=}{Smith et al., 2004} &
  \multirow{-1}[2]{=}{Rat Rat Mouse} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{Stress Type} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{short description} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{ABC} &
  \multirow{-1}{=}{PND100} &
  Female &
  $\leftrightarrow$ No Change &
  \multirow{-1}[4]{=}{description that is a bit long to add detail} &
  results   that are a little longer and need to go here too ABCD 1234 \\ \hline
  \hline
Smith et al., 2004 &
  Rat   Rat Mouse &
  Stress   Type &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
  ABC &
  PND100 &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
  NOT   TESTED &
  NOT   TESTED \\ \hline
Smith et al., 2004 &
  Rat Rat Mouse &
  Stress   Type &
  long   description bla bla bla bla &
  ABC &
  PND100 &
  Male &
  ↑   Result &
  description   that is a bit long to add detail &
  results   that are a little long too          \\
  \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @Zarko ! I haven't had a chance to try this yet, but will this work in the longtable environment as I have many, many rows?

Comment: @DS14, MWE use `longtable` table. This means, that table can span as many pages as you wish. Table in it span two pages, but I show only first. Since your document example you not define first head, first foot and last foot, I also left them out. If you interested for them, I can add them to my MWE.